# Django UserCreationForm only displays inside my HTML file when i dont extend from my base HTML

Tags: python, html, django, forms

As the title suggests im having some difficulty getting this form to display when i extend from base.html

Code that doesn't display my form but displays my base.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Sign Up{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

code that does display my form properly

```
{% block title %}Sign Up{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Do you have related body block tags in your base.html? Please post your base.html

Comment: @Razenstein this was it, thanks